# R bin non numeric values

Tags: r

I know I can use cut to bin numeric values.  I want to bin non-numeric values.  Consider this dataframe:

```
color <- c("Red","Blue","Green","Gray","Black")
dataframe <- data.frame(id,color)
```

I want to create a dataframe that looks like this:

```
 id  color Group
  1    Red  R
  2   Blue  B
  3  Green  G
  4   Gray  G  
  5  Black  B
```

I can create a function and call lapply.  Is there a pre-built function that already does this for me where I just pass in the conditional expression?

Comment: perhaps `dataframe$Group <- substr(dataframe$color, 1, 1)`?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to map values to new, binned, values.

```
color <- c("Red","Blue","Green","Gray","Black")
dataframe <- data.frame(id = 1:5, color)

library(plyr)

dataframe$Group <- mapvalues(dataframe$color, from = c("Red","Blue","Green","Gray","Black"), 
                                              to = c("R", "B", "G", "G", "B"))

  id color Group
1  1   Red     R
2  2  Blue     B
3  3 Green     G
4  4  Gray     G
5  5 Black     B
```